# ProgressBar doesn't update when program running on weak computers

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading

When I run the program in one fast computer, the `ProgressBar` and a `Label`(that write the progress too) gets perfectly updated. When I run it on a weak computer (like PIV or old c2d) the `ProgressBar` and the form stay freezed (but the program run until it finishes).

How can I resolve that? With background worker?

Comment: Are you using WPF or Windows Forms?

Answer (score 3):

If you're using a progress bar, I'm guessing whatever the task is is definitely long enough to warrant a background/worker thread. There are lots of options (BackgroundWorker, spinning up your own thread, etc). [`BackgroundWorker`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) is probably the easiest.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should put your processing into a background thread. Using a background worker is a good idea, because you can simply update the controls from its `ProgressChanged` event.

Answer (score -1):

There are some methods that allow the UI to be refereshed in long-running tasks.

1- run the task in another tread/in an anychronous method call and then using this.Invoke to change the progressbar.
2- Force the UI to refresh at some points in the task by calling Application.DoEvents() in winforms for instance.

Comment: Application.DoEvents() is not recommended.